# Access to file path on form upload with Iron Params

Tags: rust, iron

I tried to get the temporary path of an uploaded file using [Iron params](https://github.com/iron/params). I have this request handler:

```
fn handler(req: &mut Request) -> IronResult<Response> {
    let tmp_file_name = req.get_ref::<Params>().unwrap().find(&["file"]).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", tmp_file_name);
    Ok( Response::with( (status::Ok, "Lorem Ipsum.") ) )
}
```

It displays something like this:

```
File { path: "/xxx/yyy", filename: Some("file.txt"), size: 123 }
```

But if I try to access to the path:

```
println!("{:?}", tmp_file_name.path());
```

It does not compile:

```
error: attempted access of field `path` on type `&params::Value`, 
but no field with that name was found
```

I think I missed some basics about type, but I don't know where to (re)start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`params::Value`](https://github.com/iron/params/blob/67bf20edabf8dd955e67cf8e14a2b34bb492d1bb/src/lib.rs#L41) is not a [`params::File`](https://github.com/iron/params/blob/67bf20edabf8dd955e67cf8e14a2b34bb492d1bb/src/lib.rs#L151-L181), but an enum that [could contain](https://github.com/iron/params/blob/67bf20edabf8dd955e67cf8e14a2b34bb492d1bb/src/lib.rs#L57) a [`params::File`](https://github.com/iron/params/blob/67bf20edabf8dd955e67cf8e14a2b34bb492d1bb/src/lib.rs#L151-L181).

This should work with proper imports (untested):

```
match req.get_ref::<Params>().unwrap().find(&["file"]) {
  Some(&Value::File(ref file)) => {
    println!("{:?}", file.path())
  }
  _ => {
    println!("no file");
  }
}
```

Comment: Oops it does not work "expected `&params::Value`, found `params::Value`" in "Some(Value::File(file))"

Comment: Try `Some(Value::File(file))` -> `Some(&Value::File(file))`.

Comment: "cannot move out of borrowed content". It works with `Some(&Value::File(ref file))`. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the edit! I wanted to confirm if it works before editing my answer as I don't have an Iron app setup locally to test myself.